# Application won't start debugging on iPhone

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio

After upgrading my iPhone to iOS7 and Xamarin Studio to version 4.0.12 (build 3) i can't debug my application.

After the application has been deployed to the device(I'm getting the `Application installed` message in the "Deploy to Device" window) the top status window is showing the connection 
icon and displays `Waiting for debugger to connect... The application has been built and uploaded, or is alread...` (the message get truncated and I can't seem to get the entire message).

What can I do?

It's noteworthy that:

1. It doesn't happen in another application
2. This application uses a binding library
3. Installing and running an Ad Hoc build on the iPhone works (although iOS7 broke the UI...)

Answer (score 0):

You should download the corresponding XCode 5.x for iOS 7. You may also need to upgrade your Macs Operating System to 10.8.3+ as well.